# How to remove admin rights from guest account?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, guest-account

I discovered that the Guest account on my computer has Administrator rights. Yep, my kids are much clever than I thought…Unfortunately I am unable to remove admin rights from Guest account.

Any ideas how to get back to “standard user” rights?
(Windows 7 Enterprise)

Comment: What makes you think it has admin rights? By default, unless you specifically changed something, the built-in guest account does not have administrator rights.

Comment: Delete the profile simple solution why are you unable to remove the permission it was added after all

Answer (score 7):

- Open an [**elevated** administrator shell](https://superuser.com/questions/728810/how-do-you-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7-with-a-shortcut-key/728824#728824).
- **Execute**:

  `net localgroup Administrators /del Guest`
- **Check** by doing:

  `net localgroup Administrators`

Should work on **any version** of Windows, since NT, 2000... to Windows 8.1, and in any **flavour** (Pro, Home, Ultimate, Server... etc), whether you try it in **local or remote** (telnet, SSH... etc) access.

Note that on your specific **language localization**, the name of the **user** and/or **group** could differ. Example for spanish Windows:

```
net localgroup Administradores /del Invitado
```

Answer (score 3):

(Make sure you are logged in as an administrator, not the guest account or a user account.)

Go to start > run >> and type in `lusrmgr.msc` and hit enter.

[image: run]

You should see something like this

[image: lusrmgr initial screen with users and groups]

In the list of options, select guest and double click it.

[image: lusrmgr screenshot]

Select the `Member of` tab.

[image: lusmgr guest member of]

There you should be able to ascertain what groups Guest belongs to.

Alternatively, you can select groups in the left hand navigation bar and see all users that belong to a particular group.

Comment: This won't work on home editions FYI

Comment: That's frustrating, @nhinkle. How do I manage users in home editions of Windows 7?

Comment: you can still use `control userpasswords2` to change group membership. For more advanced things like enabling/disabling accounts you'd have to use `net.exe` - specifically `net user`, `net accounts`, and `net localgroup`.

Comment: @Asagi If a post answers your question, please mark it as the correct answer by clicking the checkbox beside it. This will let other people know your question is answered.