# Windows method to detect ARP Poisoning in my local network (LAN)?

Tags: windows, networking, security, arp

*(This question comes from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/738864/how-to-identify-wireless-device-that-is-poisoning-router), and is intended to remain as a reference question/answer pair for more generic ARP network detection not limited to WiFi, or without the need of the specific explanations given to that original poster of the question)*

As long as the **ARP Poisoning attack** is becoming more usual ([dSploit](http://dsploit.net/) for Android, [Cain&Abel](http://www.oxid.it/cain.html)  for Windows, or several methods for [Linux](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/arpspoof)) in public places (Bar, Pubs, Restaurants, Commercial Centers, Cybers... etc), I would like to know about some **fast and simple method to detect it** from my Windows laptop computer, whether I am in a cable or wireless network.

Do I need for [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) captures and long readings of cryptic traffic data? Do I need of a FireWall (sometimes they disturb more than they help)? It is mandatory to have something like [Snort](http://www.snort.org/) and become a guru capable of understanding all that data?
Isn't there any simple method that even works in out-of-the-stock Windows computers?

Answer (score 2):

*(This answer is an adaptation of [this one](https://superuser.com/a/738895/268923) to make it non-WiFi dependant, simpler, faster, and more appropriate to this other question)*

Indeed, there is a **simple method** that is supposed to work in all cases.
Under **ARP Poisoning cases**, there should necessarily be a **duplicate MAC Address** (AKA Physical Address) on your local network (AKA subnetwork or LAN), so the trick to detect it is simple: just **list the ARP Table** (this is: all the MACs that your computer knows) and **check for duplicates**.
The usual duplicate uses to be the gateway (router, that connects you to internet).
Method:

1.- Open [Shell as Administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/728810/how-do-you-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7-with-a-shortcut-key/728824#728824):

```
cmd
```

2.- **Clear ARP cache** (for possible remaining disconnected devices on your network) and wait a few seconds (30 seconds should enough):
arp -d -a
3.- **List ARP Table** by executing (the output is just an example case of poisoning):

```
c:\>arp -a
Interface: 192.168.11.108 --- 0x2
Internet Address IP Physical Address    Type
192.168.0.1         00-17-31-3f-d3-a9   dynamical
192.168.0.102       50-e5-49-c5-47-15   dynamical
192.168.0.107       00-17-31-3f-d3-a9   dynamical
192.168.0.108       00-0a-e4-a0-7f-78   dynamical
```

4.- Look for duplicates in the ARP table. In my example, the router `192.168.0.1` and the device at `192.168.0.107` share the same MAC, so the chances are very high that the computer `192.168.0.107` is the poisoner.

NOTE: the `cmd` shell as administrator is only needed for step 2 (Clear ARP cache). The rest of the process can be done from normal unprivileged shell.

- **There could be more than one device poisoning on my LAN?** Well... it is not usual, and lacks some sense: the poisoning process could (not allways) slowdown (maybe not much) or even crash the entire network, and poisoning the router uses to send a lot of traffic to the poisoner (could ever hang the poisoner device). But it could happen. Anyway, you still can detect it using this method. Just search for more duplicates.
- **Could any other device but the router be the poisoned one?** Yes. Sometimes the interesting part is to intercept data sent to a network printer, a NAS, files sent between computers... etc.
- **The poisoner is not a router. Why, if the data are sent to the poisoner instead of to the router, I still have internet running?** Because the poisoner resends the traffic to the router, in an attempt that you won't notice anything. This is a part of what is usually called "Man in the Middle (MITM)" attack.