# A folder misbehaving on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have a single folder that is exhibiting some strange behavior in the explorer

my directory looks something like this `Documents/Parent/StrangeFolder/ChildFolders`

When I try to open any of the `ChildFolders` with a double click nothing happens.
when I am displaying the contents of `StrangeFolder` and I try to any of the `ChildFolders` I can't. It simply changes the folder name to be an edit control with the entire name hightlighted, but I can't change the cursor selection or type anything.

If I try to delete a folder from `Parent` nothing appears to happen, but I can no longer open the deleted folder. Only after refreshing the view does the folder disappear.

I have tried renaming `StrangeFolder`. I have tried copying and removing the original.

This is the only folder where I see the behavior happening. It seemed to happen after I messed things up and tried doing a `rmdir` on the command line to remove `StrangeFolder` and create it again. `rmdir` gave me some errors about it not being empty so I think I tried doing `rmdir -f -r` to try to make it remove the whole thing, but I don't remember.

Comment: The correct Windows command to remove a directory tree is `rd /s <Path>`, by the way.

Comment: I have GnuWin Installed. I tend to use those commands more frequently out of habbit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try (in order of possible solution and complexity):

- 1.- **ScanDisk**: Open [Elevated Console](https://superuser.com/questions/728810/how-do-you-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7-with-a-shortcut-key/728824#728824) and do (for that drive):
  `chkdsk c: /f`
  look if there were corrected problems by [reviewing the ChkDsk log](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/96938-check-disk-chkdsk-read-event-viewer-log.html).
- 2.- This may lack a bit of logic, but sometimes a **defrag** has solved me this kind of problem. According to @LPChip comment, defrag rearranges files and folders on the harddrive and then rebuilds the file allocation table.
- 3.- Boot **Linux**, any BootCD (like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop))or Pendrive could do, or any **Recovery** CD/Pendrive (like [@Active BootDisk](http://www.lsoft.net/bootdisk.aspx)) and **try to access** the folder. If there is important to recover data inside, backup it.
- 4.- **Create a partition image** to some clone disk tool, like *PartImage*, restore it to another partition or virtual device, and try to access the folder. Some image partition tools allow data accessing without restoring it. [This method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39113/mount-ntfs-image-file-created-using-partimage) worked for me some times (not very often, and I must say I am not very sure about *why* does it work), but it is long, a bit awkward, and requires an extra harddisk, so I only use it for important data recovery and as a last hope. *@Active BootDisk* wear inside some tools for this, but maybe it will require registration to be used, so I better suggest [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/).
- An extra suggestion: check SMART status of the hard disk. Folder misbehaving problems sometime precede hard disk (whether spinning or SSD) failures. I don't know if Windows reports this, but you can use [AIDA64](http://www.aida64.com/downloads), for example (try-out version available to download).

Comment: Good call on defrag. The reason why it works is because defrag rearranges files and folders on the harddrive and then rebuild the file allocation table.

Comment: I did steps 1 and 2 of this. I then ran `sfc /scannow` and the problem didn't go away. A showed the IT guy at work and he right clicked on one of the folders and clicked `open folder location` and the problem went away. I also don't see the `open folder location` option in the context menu any more either. All in all the folder is fixed and I'm going to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Well... computers behave sometimes like an illogical thing, you know. It is possible that step 1 or 2 solved your problem but something was left to be repaired on the next operating system reboot, so you didn't notice until much later. Anyway, if you arrive to know what in hell was the origin of the problem, please let us know. And thanks for your expanding, @LPChip. I have added it to my answer for future references.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a corruption in the File Allocation Table (or how that thing called in an NTFS partition) where it thinks a file is there while it actually isn't. The only way to get rid of this is to format the drive. This does mean the entire drive will be erased, so this usually is not an option.

Maybe a chkdsk can fix it.

Comment: Worth a shot. Starting chkdsk now.