# My directory has become recursive. How can I remove it?

Tags: windows, windows-8, filesystems

The directory structure of one of my folders has become recursive or something, making an almost endless loop until I cannot go further down:

> D:\prog\ai2\oving5\robotst\out\PRODUC~1\robots\out\PRODUC~1\robots\out\PRODUC~1\robots\out\PRODUC~1\robots\out\PRODUC~1\robots\out\PRODUC~1\robots\out\PRODUC~1\robots\out\PRODUC~1\robots\out\PRODUC~1\robots\out\PRODUC~1\robots\out\production\robots

How did this happen?

Trying to delete any file/directory somewhere in this path through Explorer fails with:

> The source file names(s) are larger than is supported by the file
>   system. Try moving to a location which has a shorter path name, or try
>   renaming to shorter name(s) before attempting this operation.

Moving anything fails with the same message. I've tried renaming the directories to single letter names, but it's still too long. I've also tried shift+delete to bypass Recycle Bin.

Trying through command line (`del` and `rd`), nothing happens. No errors message, but the directories remain.

I've even tried removing the directory in Linux with `rm -rf robotst`, but it fails with

> rm: cannot remove "path": File or path name too long

Any ideas on how to remove the folders, and why this has happened?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A folder misbehaving on windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/745073/a-folder-misbehaving-on-windows-7)

Comment: Can't really say that looks anything like my situation here.

Comment: try this one http://superuser.com/questions/78434/tool-for-deleting-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete (I would start with an `7zip` answer /to use it as 'alternative explorer'/, it always worked flawlessly for me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool for deleting directories with path/names too long for normal delete](http://superuser.com/questions/78434/), [How do I delete a folder which is nested quite deep and avoid "File name too long"?](http://superuser.com/questions/256105/)

Comment: @and31415 I don't think those will help either since the OP's path is infinite.

Comment: Can you go to `D:\prog\ai2\oving5\robotst\out\PRODUC~1` and show me what the `DIR` command shows?

Comment: I wonder which kind of link loop this is. Windows supports pretty many types, junction points, symlinks hardlinks and some others I forgot about. Using the `dir` command as @dsolimano suggests should enable you to distinguish symlinks from the rest of them

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/981)