# CMD with shortcut?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, cmd.exe

There's already one question in this forum about doing this:  [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/728810/how-do-you-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7-with-a-shortcut-key), but it don't do the same as GNOME/Linux, who keeps the terminal in memory, so when you press the shortcut, it opens the terminal instantly. Is there anyway to achieve this on windows?

Answer (score 1):

Drop a shortcut to cmd.exe on the desktop, right click and specify a shortcut key (for example <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, as in the screenshot below). Works immediately.

[image]

Comment: Yup, it works, I've done this. But the problem is that you have to wait a few seconds, since its not already in memory, as in linux...

Comment: I'm not aware of the ability to either preload cmd.exe, or keep it in memory. It's pretty light though, takes a fraction of a second for me to load here.

Comment: I just tied it to CTRL+SHIFT+1, which makes a one handed shortcut press very easy. That's as fast as you can get it I reckon :)

Comment: Wish I had an sdd ;)

Comment: Smaller ones are pretty cheap, you can run a dual setup - OS and programs on the system SSD, documents and other files on a bigger HDD. Been doing that for a long time

Comment: If you don't close it the shortcut key will switch to it. The shortcut key both starts the program if not open and switches to the window if already opened.

Comment: Also if you want it hidden from the taskbar see this program https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/04/this-uses-inbuilt-compilers-in-windows.html.